# Rotation gesture produces undesired rotation

Tags: swift, uiimageview, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

I need to rotate an UIImageview on user's motion using just one finger motion.  For that I use a rotation gesture and then override touchesMoved with this code:

```
  override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    if touch!.view === rotateImageView {
        let position = touch!.locationInView(self.view)

        let target = rotateImageView.center
        let angle = atan2(target.y-position.y, target.x-position.x)
        rotateImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    }
  }
```

This works as long as the user stop to touch the screen and make the motion on another part of the screen. On that scenario the UIImageview rotates on undesired position when the user starts to move the finger. I need to keep the original rotation position of the UIImageview to avoid this but I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

This gif shows the current behavior on the project prototype I have.  As you can see when I start to rotate on the right side the flame icon suddenly appears near the touch point, that's what I want to prevent.

**UPDATE Aug 23-2016**

I used Matt and Dasem suggestion of using CGAffineTransformRotate but I still see the jump.  I took Dasem code and adapted to  my project like follows (Let me know if the adaption is wrong):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    origin = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view))!

    //save the current transform
    tempTransform = rotateImageView.transform

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touchPoint = touches.first?.locationInView(self.view)

    xOffSet = CGVector(dx:(origin.x)-rotateImageView.center.x, dy:(origin.x) - rotateImageView.center.y)
    yOffSet = CGVector(dx:touchPoint!.x - rotateImageView.center.x, dy:touchPoint!.y - rotateImageView.center.y)

    let angle = atan2(yOffSet.dy,yOffSet.dx) - atan2(xOffSet.dy,xOffSet.dx)
    rotateImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(tempTransform, angle)

}
```

This change produces a similar effect when user touches a different region of the touchscreen. In this gif I've changed the image and remove the icons to make the effect more noticeable.

[image]

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

Reapplied code with Jasem update and it worked , the following code solved the problem without using subclassing

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    origin = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view))!
    xOffSet = CGVector(dx:(origin.x)-rotateImageView.center.x, dy:(origin.y) - rotateImageView.center.y)
    startingAngle = atan2(xOffSet.dy,xOffSet.dx)

    //save the current transform
    tempTransform = rotateImageView.transform
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touchPoint = touches.first?.locationInView(self.view)
    yOffSet = CGVector(dx:touchPoint!.x - rotateImageView.center.x, dy:touchPoint!.y - rotateImageView.center.y)
    let angle = atan2(yOffSet.dy,yOffSet.dx)

    let deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle!
    rotateImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(tempTransform, deltaAngle)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    startingAngle = nil
}

//reset in case drag is cancelled
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    rotateImageView.transform = tempTransform
    startingAngle = nil
}
```

Comment: I'm happy that you have it working, but there was never any need to save the current transform as an instance property, and my answer is still right.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you to see an example of a rotatable view: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p597knob/ch25p870knob/MyKnob.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to change self.superview to self.view (mine is subclass)

```
var xOffSet:CGVector = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
var yOffSet:CGVector = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
var origin:CGPoint = CGPointZero
var tempTransform=CGAffineTransform()
var startingAngle:CGFloat?


   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    origin = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.superview))!
    xOffSet = CGVector(dx:(origin.x)-self.center.x, dy:(origin.y) - self.center.y)
    startingAngle = atan2(xOffSet.dy,xOffSet.dx)

    //save the current transform
    tempTransform = self.transform
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touchPoint = touches.first?.locationInView(self.superview)
    yOffSet = CGVector(dx:touchPoint!.x - self.center.x, dy:touchPoint!.y - self.center.y)
    let angle = atan2(yOffSet.dy,yOffSet.dx)

    let deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle!
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(tempTransform, deltaAngle) 
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {  
  startingAngle = nil
}

//reset in case drag is cancelled
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.transform = tempTransform
        startingAngle = nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dasem, I still have the issue, please see update

Comment: in this part xOffSet = CGVector(dx:(origin.x)-rotateImageView.center.x, dy:(origin.x) - rotateImageView.center.y)   change the second origin.x to origin.y

Comment: also i have updated my answer (for clarity purpose, and some improvements)

Comment: Working fine now :)

Comment: I am trying to use this code to do something similar to this project. But I am experiencing some problems during the code translation to the swift 4 edition. "I guess". CGAffineTransform seems to have not the "rotate from previous transform" option and I do not know how I can use it. I searched everywhere but nothing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are saying

```
rotateImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
```

So whatever transform the image view has already (from the previous rotation) is *thrown away* and completely *replaced* by a new transform starting at `angle`. That's the "jump" you are seeing.

What you want to do is apply a rotation transform *to the existing transform* of the image view. You can do that by calling CGAffineTransformRotate, instead of CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Comment: Thanks for the response @matt, I still have the issue, please see update